# Interactive brokers historical data availability

Tags: programming, interactive-brokers

I'm considering Interactive Brokers because of the IBrokers package for R.

[On this site](http://xavierib.github.io/twsapidocs/historical_limitations.html#hd_availability) there is a small section on data availability and I'm having a hard time understanding the table.
Lets say I have 10,000 dollars in my account and I want 15 minutes bars. Does it mean I can get few thousand observations (one year of 15 minutes bars).
I'm only concerned about the S&P 500 index.
I'm mainly concerned with the amount of observation since I'm building a statistical model and I want to use e.g. 15 minutes bars or even 5 minutes bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean I can get few thousand observations.

Probably, yes, but I did not try it myself.

Using R package IBrokers, namely, `reqHistoricalData` function, I pump out the base of several years OHLC prices for 1,700 shares, store it in MySQL, update it once a week and scan it in search of suitable purchases.

> (one year of 15 minutes bars). I'm only concerned about the S&P 500 index.

Maybe something like this:

```
test3<- twsSTK("SPY")
dat <- reqHistoricalData(tws, test3, 
                  endDateTime=paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")), 
                  barSize="15 min", 
                  duration="1 Y")
```

See the details here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152138/ibrokers-twsfop-call-in-r?rq=1